# How to determine whether two sets of variables have a shared value in R?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data that contains two sets of variables, and I want to compare whether the two sets have the same value. In each line of the two sets of variables, as long as any pair of values are equal, it is marked as 1, otherwise it is 0. If the data contains missing values, I want the missing values not to participate in the comparison. If the data contains a character variable, they are still considered equal as long as its actual value is the same as that of a numeric variable.

To illustrate the problem, I generate data *a1*. I want to determine whether any values in the first group of variables (*z1* and *x1*) and the second group of variables (*z2* and *x2*) are same and generate the variable *result*.

```
a1=data.table(z1=c(1,NA,3:5),x1=c("3",4:7),z2=c(2,NA,4:6),x2=c(3,5,4,7,5))
a1$result=c(1,0,0,0,1)
```

The actual data is close to 20 million lines, and there are many variables in each group. I want to find the most efficient method. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a problem that scales poorly. After some benchmarking of (say) `as.matrix`, `apply`, `asplit`, `data.table::transpose`, etc, I haven't found one that scales reasonably beyond 50K rows.

The most direct (and, to me, palatable, performance-wise) path is the most literal:

```r
a1[, result := +(z1 == z2 | z1 == x2 | x1 == z2 | x1 == x2)]
```

This fails with `NA` values, though, so we need to be a little more careful. After some playing, I think this helper function is the most direct, since it does exactly the logic we need and is fully vectorized:

```r
`%=%` <- function(a, b) !is.na(a) & !is.na(b) & a == b
a1[, +(z1 %=% z2 | x1 %=% z2 | z1 %=% x2 | x1 %=% x2)]
# [1] 1 0 0 0 1
```

(I intentionally avoided using `` `%==%` `` since I've seen that in other packages in a way that allows `NA %==% NA` to be true. If you prefer to use `` `%==%` ``, feel free, or use some other infix operator of your choosing. It doesn't even need to be infix, that's mostly aesthetic.)

The question is how to automate this when we have more variables within each *group* (as defined by the trailing number in the variable name). For that, I propose we literally create the expression by hand and then eval/parse it.

```r
g1 = grep("1", names(a1), value = TRUE)
g2 = grep("2", names(a1), value = TRUE)
expr <- paste0(
  "+(",
  paste(outer(g1, g2, function(a, b) sprintf("%s %%=%% %s", a, b)), collapse = " | "),
  ")")
expr
# [1] "+(z1 %=% z2 | x1 %=% z2 | z1 %=% x2 | x1 %=% x2)"
```

This produces the desired results:

```r
a1[, result2 := eval(parse(text = expr))]
#       z1     x1    z2    x2 result result2
#    <num> <char> <num> <num>  <num>   <int>
# 1:     1      3     2     3      1       1
# 2:    NA      4    NA     5      0       0
# 3:     3      5     4     4      0       0
# 4:     4      6     5     7      0       0
# 5:     5      7     6     5      1       1
```

This scales well vertically. If `a1` is 5 rows, then replicating it `1e4` times produces 50K rows, etc.

```r
a1e4 <- rbindlist(replicate(1e4, a1, simplify=FALSE))    # 50K rows
system.time(a1e4[, result2 := eval(parse(text = expr))])
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.06    0.00    0.06 

a1e5 <- rbindlist(replicate(1e5, a1, simplify=FALSE))    # 500K
system.time(a1e5[, result2 := eval(parse(text = expr))])
#    user  system elapsed 
#     0.7     0.0     0.7 

a1e6 <- rbindlist(replicate(1e6, a1, simplify=FALSE))    # 5M
system.time(a1e6[, result2 := eval(parse(text = expr))])
#    user  system elapsed 
#    7.16    0.06    7.22
```

It appears to scale linearly, which means that another 4x of rows should resolve in around 30 seconds.

What about with more variables per group? (i.e., scaling *horizontally*)

```r
set.seed(42)
b1 <- copy(a1[,1:4])[, c("s1","t1","u1","v1","w1","y1", "s2","t2","u2","v2","w2","y2") :=
                         replicate(12, sample(9, .N, replace = TRUE), simplify = FALSE)]
b1
#       z1     x1    z2    x2    s1    t1    u1    v1    w1    y1    s2    t2    u2    v2    w2    y2
#    <num> <char> <num> <num> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1:     1      3     2     3     1     2     9     9     4     8     6     8     1     2     2     1
# 2:    NA      4    NA     5     5     1     5     9     2     6     2     2     5     4     7     1
# 3:     3      5     4     4     1     8     4     4     8     8     5     3     2     3     6     7
# 4:     4      6     5     7     9     7     2     5     3     4     4     8     6     6     8     4
# 5:     5      7     6     5     4     4     3     5     1     4     2     7     6     5     5     9
bg1 = grep("1", names(b1), value = TRUE)
bg2 = grep("2", names(b1), value = TRUE)
bexpr <- paste0(
  "+(",
  paste(outer(bg1, bg2, function(a, b) sprintf("%s %%=%% %s", a, b)), collapse = " | "),
  ")")
bexpr
# [1] "+(z1 %=% z2 | x1 %=% z2 | s1 %=% z2 | t1 %=% z2 | u1 %=% z2 | v1 %=% z2 | w1 %=% z2 | y1 %=% z2 | z1 %=% x2 | x1 %=% x2 | s1 %=% x2 | t1 %=% x2 | u1 %=% x2 | v1 %=% x2 | w1 %=% x2 | y1 %=% x2 | z1 %=% s2 | x1 %=% s2 | s1 %=% s2 | t1 %=% s2 | u1 %=% s2 | v1 %=% s2 | w1 %=% s2 | y1 %=% s2 | z1 %=% t2 | x1 %=% t2 | s1 %=% t2 | t1 %=% t2 | u1 %=% t2 | v1 %=% t2 | w1 %=% t2 | y1 %=% t2 | z1 %=% u2 | x1 %=% u2 | s1 %=% u2 | t1 %=% u2 | u1 %=% u2 | v1 %=% u2 | w1 %=% u2 | y1 %=% u2 | z1 %=% v2 | x1 %=% v2 | s1 %=% v2 | t1 %=% v2 | u1 %=% v2 | v1 %=% v2 | w1 %=% v2 | y1 %=% v2 | z1 %=% w2 | x1 %=% w2 | s1 %=% w2 | t1 %=% w2 | u1 %=% w2 | v1 %=% w2 | w1 %=% w2 | y1 %=% w2 | z1 %=% y2 | x1 %=% y2 | s1 %=% y2 | t1 %=% y2 | u1 %=% y2 | v1 %=% y2 | w1 %=% y2 | y1 %=% y2)"
```

Ugh, that looks bad, but the performance scales very nicely with 8 variables per group:

```r
b1e4 <- rbindlist(replicate(1e4, b1, simplify=FALSE))
system.time(b1e4[, result2 := eval(parse(text = bexpr))])
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.11    0.00    0.10 

b1e5 <- rbindlist(replicate(1e5, b1, simplify=FALSE))
system.time(b1e5[, result2 := eval(parse(text = bexpr))])
#    user  system elapsed 
#    1.03    0.00    1.03 

b1e6 <- rbindlist(replicate(1e6, b1, simplify=FALSE))
system.time(b1e6[, result2 := eval(parse(text = bexpr))])
#    user  system elapsed 
#   11.72    0.51   12.25
```

Comment: Thank you for your scalable solution. I believe many similar problems can be solved through your answer!

Answer (score 3):

Here's another generalizable method relying on the column names for each group:

```
g1 = grep("1", names(a1), value = TRUE)
g2 = grep("2", names(a1), value = TRUE)

a1[, result := as.integer(
  apply(.SD, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) any(x[g1] %in% x[g2]))
), .SDcols = c(g1, g2)]
a1
#    z1 x1 z2 x2 result
# 1:  1  3  2  3      1
# 2:  2  4  3  5      0
# 3:  3  5  4  4      0
# 4:  4  6  5  7      0
# 5:  5  7  6  5      1
```

Comment: I suggest the addition of `.SDcols = c(g1,g2)` for speed and class-safety.

Comment: Thanks for the improvement!

Comment: For the record (I think you understand, GregorThomas), the "speed" (of using `.SDcols`) is most felt when there are more columns than just the four mentioned here, and the "class-safety" is because `apply(.SD, 1, ...)` can coerce all columns to `character` if any of them are non-numeric. In this sample data neither are a factor, but it's the small things that can trip you up when adapting solutions to other datasets.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To make the problem more general, I modified `a1` to include missing values and character variables. The current solution produces strange `result=c(1,1,0,0,0)`. If row 2 is the effect of missing values, I don't understand why row 5 is misjudged.

Comment: Mixing character class in is messing this up. `apply` converts to matrix, which converts everything to character. I don't understand why, but whitespace is being introduced in the integer conversion. We can examine with `a1[, test := 
  apply(.SD, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) list(g1 = x[g1], g2 = x[g2])),
  .SDcols = c(g1, g2)]`, here `a1$test[[5]]` shows that the `z1` `5` becomes `" 5"` with a leading whitespace while the `x2` `5` becomes `"5"`. Very strange....

Comment: We can solve both issues with `function(x) any(na.omit(trimws(x[g1])) %in% na.omit(trimws(x[g2]))))`, but that's getting pretty hacky.

Comment: But a better solution might compare based on data type, comparing numerics to numerics and strings to strings... how would you want a numeric `1` compared to a string `"1"` to be handled?

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I want to compare numeric numbers with character numbers is just in case some numbers are typed incorrectly. In fact, this problem can be solved by checking and changing the type of numbers in advance . Your answer has solved my question very well, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

We may loop over the rows, find the `length` of the `intersect` between the pairs and convert to logical

```
library(data.table)
a1[, result := +(apply(.SD, 1, FUN = function(x) 
     length(intersect(x[1:2], x[3:4]))) > 0)]
```

-output

```
> a1
   z1 x1 z2 x2 result
1:  1  3  2  3      1
2:  2  4  3  5      0
3:  3  5  4  4      0
4:  4  6  5  7      0
5:  5  7  6  5      1
```

With respect to efficiency, `dapply` (from `collapse`) may be faster compared to `apply`

```
library(collapse)
a1[, result := dapply(.SD, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x)
          length(intersect(x[1:2], x[3:4])))]
```

---

Or use a vectorized option with `str_detect`

```
library(stringr)
a1[, result := +(str_detect(paste(z1, x1), paste0(z2, "|", x2)))]
```

Comment: Thank you akrun. In order to make the problem more general, I changed the variable of `a1`. Now the first solution produces the `result=c(1,1,0,0,0)`, and the last two solutions produce the `result=c(1,1,0,0,1)`, both of which seem to have some problems.

Comment: @Vesper It was not mentioned about. the `NA`.  If there are then use `na.omit` i.e. `a1[, +(apply(.SD, 1, FUN = function(x) 
      length(intersect(na.omit(x[1:2]), na.omit(x[3:4])))) > 0)]#
[1] 1 0 0 0 0`

Comment: Yes, I see. Thank you for your supplementary reply.

Answer (score 2):

> The actual data is close to 20 million lines, and there are many variables in each group. I want to find the most efficient method

You can transform to long form and join to see if there are any matches. I guess it's relatively fast.

```
# this code should work for the original question (without character vectors or NAs)
# create a row id
a1[, row_id := .I]

# specify column groups
cols1 = c("x1", "z1")
cols2 = c("x2", "z2")

# transform to long form, drop colnames, drop dupes
longDT1 = unique(melt(a1[, c("row_id", ..cols1)], id.vars="row_id")[, !"variable"])
longDT2 = unique(melt(a1[, c("row_id", ..cols2)], id.vars="row_id")[, !"variable"])

# find any matches
w = longDT1[longDT2, on=.(row_id, value), which=TRUE, nomatch=0]

# find associated row_ids
match_row_ids = longDT1[w, unique(row_id)]

# flag rows
a1[, res := FALSE][match_row_ids, res := TRUE]
```

Note: If you have a mix of character values in some columns:

- You can use `type.convert` as part of data cleaning to get the correct type from the start.
- If you must have strings, then both `value` columns in longDT1 and longDT2 must be converted to strings.

Comment: While the join will be very fast, I would think the `melt` steps might slow down the whole process... it'd be very interesting to see benchmarks.

Comment: @GregorThomas Yeah, I agree. My guess is that since `any`/`intersect` needs to be called once per row, when there are enough rows the approach here with melt x2 + join should be faster. One other problem with the melt might be that you run into a table with 2bn rows (exceeding into the max length of a vector). So for the OP's example with 20m rows, if there are 100 columns in each group, there would be an issue.

Comment: Thank you Frank, your answer gives me another idea. I have just modified the question to make `a1` contain more diverse data situations.

Comment: @Vesper Good to know -- I've made an edit. If the strings are there in error (ie, they are actually numbers but in the wrong format), then probably better to convert them to the right type before this step. If they need to be strings (eg, some are "3" and some are "foo"), then you can still use any of the solutions here, I think.

Comment: Thank you for your patient reply. My problem can be solved.